# Binding move-only objects to functions (for a thread pool implementation)

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming

I recently implemented a thread pool using `std::function`s. I only supported functions taking no arguments on the assumption that there would be no need to have them - one could just bind the argument to the `std::function` or capture it in a lambda.

I quickly realised the limitation with this approach - `std::function` requires bound objects to be copyable (I wanted to bind a `std::unique_ptr`). Binding by reference is also not an option since it's not safe in asynchronous contexts. The solution I've come up with is to support functions with arguments and store the parameters alongside the function. My implementation for storing parameters is below. I've left out the actual thread pool part and all the asynchronous bits and bobs because it's unnecessary noise.

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

template <typename TupleT, std::size_t... I>
void invoke_impl(TupleT&& t, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    std::get<0>(t)(std::move(std::get<1 + I>(t))...);
}

template <typename... ArgTypes>
class thread_pool
{
    // First element is the function to be invoked. Remaining
    // elements are the function arguments.
    using job_t = std::tuple<
            std::function<void(ArgTypes...)>,
            ArgTypes...>;

    std::queue<job_t> _jobs;

    constexpr static auto param_index_sequence()
    {
        return std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ArgTypes)>();
    }

public:
    template <typename FuncT, typename ...Args>
    void post_job(FuncT&& func, Args&&... args)
    {
        _jobs.emplace(
                std::forward<FuncT>(func),
                std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    // This would normally be run by the worker threads.
    void run_job()
    {
        job_t j = std::move(_jobs.front());
        _jobs.pop();
        invoke_impl(std::move(j), param_index_sequence());
    }
};

struct obj
{
    obj() { std::cout << "constructed\n"; }
    ~obj() { std::cout << "destructed\n"; }
    obj(const obj&) { std::cout << "copied\n"; }
    obj& operator=(const obj&) { std::cout << "copy-assigned\n"; return *this; }
    obj(obj&&) { std::cout << "moved\n"; }
    obj& operator=(obj&&) { std::cout << "move-assigned\n"; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
    thread_pool<obj> tp;

    // 4 moves
    tp.post_job([] (obj) {}, obj());
    tp.run_job();

    // 3 moves
    tp.post_job([] (const obj&) {}, obj());
    tp.run_job();
}
```

I'd especially appreciate thoughts on the following:

- Is this the best approach?
- Can I reduce the number of potentially-expensive moves required? Perhaps storing the arguments separately in a `std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>` would be a better option...
- Am I using `std::move` and `std::forward` optimally?
- Can I make my templates more flexible/robust? e.g. by using `std::remove_reference`, `std::remove_cv` etc.
- I've intentionally kept to C++14 (hence my using `std::get<0>(j)(...)` rather than `std::invoke`). I'd like to keep to C++14 but I'd be interested about newer features that make my implementation simpler or even completely redundant.

Answer (score 2):

> - Is this the best approach?

While it is a nice workaround, it is not a *generic* solution to the problem. Ideally, you would create a C++14-compatible implementation of [`std::move_only_function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function).

> - Can I reduce the number of potentially-expensive moves required? Perhaps storing the arguments separately in a `std::unique_ptr<std::tuple<ArgTypes...>>` would be a better option...

`std::unique_ptr` introduces its own overhead, so it might not be a better option. You can however remove some `std::move`s. For example, in `run_job()`, you don't need to move, pop and then invoke, you can just do:

```
std::invoke_impl(std::move(_jobs.front()), param_index_sequence());
_jobs.pop();
```

> - Am I using std::move and std::forward optimally?

In `post_job()`, you declare the template parameter pack `Args`, but you should have used `ArgTypes` instead. This allows better type deduction, for example it allows you to write:

```
tp.post_job([] (const obj&) {}, {});
```

> - Can I make my templates more flexible/robust? e.g. by using `std::remove_reference`, `std::remove_cv` etc.

I don't think there is any reason here to use that.

> - I've intentionally kept to C++14 (hence my using `std::get<0>(j)(...)` rather than `std::invoke()`). I'd like to keep to C++14 but I'd be interested
>   about newer features that make my implementation simpler or even completely
>   redundant.

C++23's `std::move_only_function` will make it redundant.

If you would restructure `job_t` like so:

```
using job_t = std::pair<
    std::function<void(ArgTypes...)>,
    std::tuple<ArgTypes...>
>;
```

Then you can emplace jobs like so:

```
_jobs.emplace(
    std::forward<FuncT>(func),
    std::make_tuple<ArgTypes...>(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...)
);
```

And then the implementation fo `invoke_impl()` becomes much simpler; either:

```
t.first(std::move(std::get<I>(t.second))...);
```

Or using C++17's [`std::apply()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/apply):

```
std::apply(t.first, std::move(t.second));
```

And at that point, `invoke_impl()` becomes redundant, and you could rewrite `run_job()` like so:

```
void run_job() {
    auto& j = _jobs.front();
    std::apply(j.first, std::move(j.second));
    _jobs.pop();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is the the `std::move` in the call to `std::forward_as_tuple` required/desirable? Why that and not a `std::forward`?

Comment: Ah hm, I guess `std::make_tuple<ArgTypes...>(std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...)` would be the best here.